# Storing unparsed HL7 2.x messages into a sql database

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, btahl7

We are recieving HL7 2.x using the BTAHL7 accelerator.  I want to dump the raw HL7 message to a sql table, with some discrete data including control id and others.  My receive location is using the BTAHL72XRecievePipeline component.  Is it possible to subscribe to the raw message, instead of the parsed xml format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to us a custom pipeline component, something like this: http://codebetter.com/jefflynch/2006/04/08/biztalk-server-2006-archive-pipeline-component/

You can retrieve the raw message as the first step in the pipeline.

Answer (score -2):

The UltraPort MS SQL Schema Engine does exactly what you're looking for. That's all that it does, it's very fast and very good at it, and has free fully functional trial. It sets up in literally minutes and they've got really good customer service. If you call in they'll walk you through a 10-15 minute example of importing HL7 messages (and actually encourage you to use your own HL7 data if you have any). 10-15 minutes will answer 90% of any questions you might ever have and it includes downloading and installing the software.

Home Page: http://www.hermetechnz.com/EasyHL7/prod_sql.asp
Online Help: http://www.hermetechnz.com/Documentation/UltraPort/MSSQL/index.html

It stores both the unparsed HL7 message as well as breaking it into parsed data tables as well as (optionally) storing the unparsed SEGMENTS as individual rows.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this something for BizTalk?